# PHP Socket Server Script Infinite loop gives null response

Tags: php, ios, web-services, sockets, chat

We are developing an iphone app which is basically a chat app.We are using php as webservice platform.We decided to use php sockets as a chat server.

We developed a script which we run in infinite loop using SSH and then send json data as a request via iphone.

However after some X amount of time the response is NULL from socket server.

Im not sure why this is happening. We have set the execution time limit of php script of infinite too.

Comment: And are you sure the script is running? (use ```ps```) Also, did you know abaout [Ratchet library](http://socketo.me/) (PHP sockets management), maybe it suits your needs better than custom solution...

Comment: Im using nohup to run it endlessly.